# Optimizing Ansible Transport\SSH for Unconventional Networks

Tags: networking, optimization, ssh, ansible

I'm wondering how to optimise Ansible to work with a network radically different to one where use cases where Accelerate and default might not necessarily be beneficial.

In this scenario I'm not dealing with a virtual network, nor am I dealing with servers. I'm dealing with hundreds of embedded, with a rather unique network design, with downside of faults in hosts or cabling on the network may cause periodic connectivity changes to neighbouring hosts.

This would normally result in dropped or laggy SSH sessions on an individual SSH conneciton, but unfortunately cause Ansible to hang sometimes on particular hosts and Timeout change alone doesn't seem to make any difference.

Could anybody provide some information about what parameters would be best for managing configuration changes and install updates on a network where drop outs may occur during a session on or connected to particular hosts, so longer lived sessions may not be beneficial. In particular some advice on these areas in context to this use scenario

1. ssh vs paramiko
2. control persist, pipelining and timeout params
3. accelerate or no?
4. evaluating suitability for number of specified forks to run

Comment: Have you considered pull mode? https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull

Comment: Mxx - Yeah I have considered pull mode - it's a good idea for software updates for sure, but I'm also using it to do automated checks where pull isn't practical. 
Kashyap - Ansible should fine for the purpose over straight ssh and easier to manage inventory than parallel-ssh. I'm not doing insane things here - just pushing (small) packages every now and then, and of course system checks as mentioned which only needs to run a few shell scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working in a network where the connection might be lost 'during' execution of a play/task then I'm not sure if (read: I don't think) ansible saves the context of execution so often as to recover from such issues.

If your network is bad, you should fix that.

Assuming you already knew all that and: If your network is bad but you can't fix it then the params of interest would be #2 and possibly #3 that you listed.

Change #2 to ensure SSH doesn't try to reuse the connections (doesn't persist). This will slow down the playbook executions but will provide better stability.

Change #3 IF you have to transfer large files AND you're using paramiko or ansible older than 1.5.

For completeness: #1 is kinda no-brainer, don't use paramiko unless you have no choice. So although you list it as something you have a choice in, for practical purposes ansible expects you use SSH as there are many disadvantages of using paramiko over SSH and only one advantage, if you donno the advantage then probably you don't need it. :-)

Even after all these settings, if your connection is lost during execution of a task then ansible probably can't do anything except show you an error message. The only thing that will help you deal with these situations is idempotency of your plays/tasks. So that you can just run it in a loop until your playbook runs successfully and makes 0 changes.

Comment: Thanks - it's a situation where I don't have a choice about the network except optimizing via configuration changes - no physical access. Sometimes your job is to make the best of what was done before you joined a project and this is one of those situations. It's unconventional because each node is a bridge, and thus needs to stabilise when topology changes are detected.